# Navigate to a UIViewController from a UIAlertView in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uialertcontroller

I am new to Swift and iOS development. I have been trying to create an app-wide check for internet connectivity, that allows the user to retry (reload the current view). The `checkInternetConnection()` function below is called during `viewWillAppear()` in my `BaseUIViewController` class.

The `Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()` connectivity-check works fine. But so far, I have not been able to figure out a way to reload the current view after the user presses the 'Retry' button in the alert. in fact, I have not been able to figure out a way to reload the current view in any scenario.

One thing I know I am doing wrong in the following attempt (since there is a compile error telling me so), is that I am passing a `UIViewController` object as a parameter instead of a `string` on this line: `self.performSegueWithIdentifier(activeViewController, sender:self)`, but I suspect that this is not my only mistake.

```
func checkInternetConnection() {
    if (Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()) {
    print("Internet connection OK")
} else {
    print("Internet connection FAILED")
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Error!", comment: "Connect: error"), message: NSLocalizedString("Could not connect", comment: "Connect: error message"), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Retry", comment: "Connect: retry"), style: .Default, handler: { action in
        print("Connection: Retrying")
        let navigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        let activeViewController: UIViewController = navigationController.visibleViewController!
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(activeViewController, sender:self)
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: its `performSegueWithIdentifier` not `performSegueWithViewController` so you have to use the identifier (String) of the segue (you can set this on storyboard), or you can simply use `presentViewController` to present it.

Comment: Thanks, but I can not type a string value here, since I do not know which view the user received the alert on (and hence, I do not know which view to present to the user when they press 'Retry'). It needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Then create a dynamic string based on those next vc you have and put there...?

Comment: Calling `self.presentViewController(activeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` instead of `self.performSegueWithIdentifier(activeViewController, sender:self)` crashes at runtime.

Comment: @Tj3n I would like to try that, but I may require an example.

Comment: Just create `var identifier = ""` then do a `if else` to assign the segue identifier string to that variable? I don't know why you need an example for that

Comment: I am not familiar enough with the `UIViewController` class to know how to access the `string identifier` within an instance. Are you suggesting I `if else` through every `BaseUIViewController` child in the project? Maybe I am just naive in my hope that there is another way of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

`BaseUIViewController` can perform app-wide check for connectivity, so all your ViewControllers will be inherited from `BaseUIViewController`.

And each ViewController will have different behaviour after connectivity check.

One thing you can do is, in your `BaseUIViewController` you can define a block that performs action after connectivity check failed.

Here's the example:

```
class BaseViewUIController: UIViewController {

    var connectivityBlock: (() -> Void)?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        checkInternetConnection()
    }


    func checkInternetConnection() {
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
            print("Internet connection OK")
        } else {
            if let b = connectivityBlock {
                b()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in your inherited ViewControllers:

```
class MyViewController: BaseUIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        connectivityBlock = {
            print("Do View Refresh Here.")
        }
    }
}
```

Then After the check in `BaseUIViewController`, the code in `connectivityBlock` will be executed so that each VC can deal with it differently.

**You can also define a function in `BaseUIViewController` and each subclass will override that function, after connectivity check failed, call the function.**

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am not sure I need different behavior for each ViewController, but I suppose it will not hurt. However, I am getting a compile error _Cannot convert value of type 'testingViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'_ at the definition of `connectivityBlock()` in my `testingViewController : BaseUIViewController`. The definition contains the single line: `self.presentViewController(testingViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)` and is written directly below `super.viewDidLoad()` as in your example

Comment: So in short, your suggestion is probably sound, but my original problem persists. I need to reload the current ViewController. This should be done where you have written `print("Do View Refresh Here.")`

Comment: You're correct, you can just reload your current VC in the block as if you are reloading/refresh your view normally.

Comment: Right, and if I wanted to reload the entire current VC, could you add that to the code you posted?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get it by "reload the entire current VC", you can reload the view of the VC however you want in the block of code, i.e. show a network error view.

Comment: I am new to Swift and iOS development, so forgive me, if this is just ignorant, but I expected there would be some line of code (or several lines) that could just reload whatever ViewController the user happens to have active at the moment.

Comment: is "reload whatever ViewController" meaning that if the user is currently in VC1, and user clicks a button and navigate to VC2, and inside VC2 you do a network check, it fails, then VC2 navigate back to VC1, and VC1 navigate to VC2 again?

Comment: No. Say the user is in VC1. The user attempts to navigate to VC2. At `viewWillAppear()`, we check connectivity. If there is no connection, the user is presented with an `AlertUIController` explaining that there is no internet connection. The user can now do whatever he needs to do to ensure that the connection is working. Then the user dismisses the `AlertUIController`and at this point I want to reload VC2.

Answer (score 0):

Try navigate using application's windows

```
let destinationVC  = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window
destinationVC .present(activeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Several problems... `let destinationVC  = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window` gives compile error _"Type 'UIApplication' has no member 'shared'"_... Could this be what you meant : `let destinationVC  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window`? But then, `destinationVC .present(activeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` gives compile error _"Value of type 'UIWindows??' has no member 'present'"_

Comment: which swift version is you used  ?

Comment: Just specified it in title. Swift 2.3

Comment: and my answer in swift 3.0